# Remove object from an array of objects

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

my problem should be rather simple, but i didn't got it.

For example i have the following data from the database:

```
@user = User.all
```

then i have an other array of user

```
other_user = getting_them_from_somewhere_else
```

Now i iterate over the two arrays and check if some users are still in the database by checking for the emails:

```
@other_user.each do |o|
    @user.each do |u|
        if o["email"] == u["user_mail"]
            @user.delete(u)
            break
        end
    end

    ... do something with o ...
end
```

The method @user.delete(u) deletes the user from the database, but i just want to remove the object u from the array @user.

Comment: @user is not an array.. it's a collection to be sure, but an activerecord collection.  You can iterate across it, and do a pile of things that may feel like an array. Don't think of it as an array. It will break your heart.

Answer (score 0):

You can do vise versa

```
result_users = []
@other_user.each do |o|
    @user.each do |u|
        if o["email"] != u["user_mail"]
            result_users << u
        end
    end

    ... do something with o ...
end
here you should use result_users array which has the users you need
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@other_user.each do |o|
   @user.delete_if{|u| u["email"] == o["email"]}
end
```

It's more simple, and didn't remove of database, only remove in array. =)

Answer (score 0):

How about going the cheaper way... Less work.. 
create an array of the email addresses that you know about, and don't want anymore.

```
other_emails = @other_user.map{|o| sanitize(o["email"]) }
@users = User.where("email not in (  #{other_emails.join(',')}  )")
```

There are so many pluses to this approach.

1. there is only one loop (the map), nothing embedded.
2. there is only one array resize (the map).  We aren't calling delete which is a heavy operation on an array.
3. We only get records across the network that we care about.  Pulling down 1 million records when you only care about a handful is silly.  Strive to only read from the DB what you need.

Sometimes letting the database do things is just smarter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to use @user.email, just:

```
  @users.delete_if {|user| @other_user.include? user}
```