# Remove object from array without deleting it from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord

I'm having an issue where I just need to remove the duplicates from 2 array of active record objects. The only thing is it is removing it from the database only and I just need it removed from the array in this case. I followed this [Remove object from an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954183/remove-object-from-an-array-of-objects) and also tried a few other things and they were able to remove it from memory and explicitly remove it from array and not the database but I'm not able to replicate it. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks all!

```
company_links       = CompanyLinkType.where(company_id: company_ids, contact_linktype_id: 3)
other_company_links = CompanyLink.where(company_id: company_ids, link_type: 'Twitter')


company_links.each do |company_link|
  other_company_links.each do |other_company_link|
    # checks if id and url match, need to remove obj from company_link array
    if other_company_link.company_id == company_link.company_id && other_company_link.url == company_link.contact_link_url
      company_link.delete
      Rails.logger.info"+++++++++DELETED++++++++++"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If both arrays have same type of objects you can OR two arrays like : `company_links || other_company_links` it will return same result as you require.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the logging:

```
company_links = company_links.reject do |company_link|
    other_company_links.any? do |other_company_link|
        company_link.company_id == other_company_link.company_id && other_company_link.url == company_link.contact_link_url
    end
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I'm getting this error though. Any ideas? NoMethodError: undefined method `delete_if' for #<CompanyLinkType::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000010b8e2d10>

Comment: Ahh, you'll need to use `reject`, since `delete_if`/`reject!` are only defined on `Array`, not `Enumerable`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This returns an array not an  ActiveRecord Collection

Answer (score 0):

Change `company_link.delete` to `company_links.delete(company_link)`

Comment: hey thanks, but it still removes the entry from the database.